# c++ strange behavior returning char array from char * function

Tags: c++, arrays, winapi, pointers

how can i use the windows api without working with char and char * arrays. I want to work only with strings.

second question

```
 char * nextdir(char * cstr) {


string mystring(cstr);
mystring.erase(mystring.find("*.*\\"),4);
mystring.append("\\*.*");
char nextdiir[MAX_PATH]="0";
strncpy( nextdiir, mystring.c_str(), sizeof( mystring ) );
cout<<"NEXTDIIR function="<<nextdiir<<endl;
return nextdiir; //}
```

the next dir is an array! how can i return it from function?
what happen if i cast it to char * array?

My problem is that other function that uses the nextdir returned value is working strange!

```
void recursive(char * searchdir){   
cout<<"searchdir="<<searchdir<<endl;}
```

when im doing

```
recursive(nextdiir(foo)); //now the data printed is not the same but garbage! not like the data printed in call to nextdiir function!!
```

so i get for example

```
NEXTDIIR function=c:\windows\*.*
searchdir=garbage
//garbage is unknown characters!
```

how to fix it?

another questions!!

1)is it because i casted char array name to `char *` ?

2)how to use windows api without this char and `char *` mess . only work with strings?
3)what is the difference between char array and `char *`? the char array name is also constant pointer to the first element then what is the difference???
4)how to return char array from function in c ? in c++?
5)what is the differnce between `char *` and `const char *` ? they both the same cuz the value being pointed is unchangeable!

Please help

Comment: foo is just an array declared before that contains some default path.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a pointer to local variable `nextdiir`. When the function returns, that variable ceases to exist, leaving you with a dangling pointer. De-referencing it is undefined behaviour.

Why not return an `std::string`? Then use the `std::string::c_str()` method to get a `const char*` pointer to its underlying data.

```
std::string nextdir(const char * cstr) {
  string mystring(cstr);
  // do your stuff
  return mystring;
}
```

Comment: because i need to use FindFirstFile and the first argument is char array help me

Comment: Passing the result of `std::string::c_str()` to FindFirstFile should work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

lots of questions...

> how can i use the windows api without working with char and char * arrays. I want to work only with strings.

that will be hard, Win Api requires for some functions a pointer to char* array, you might use here `std::vector<char> vec(REQUIRED_SIZE);` pass `&vec[0]` to your api function, and assign `&vec[0]` to your `std::string` to get results into `std::string`.

> Second question

```
char nextdiir[MAX_PATH]="0";
```

is local to your function, so you are not allowd to return its pointer (it will be UB). You can as above first create `std::vector<char>` and modify it as you want, and return result as a `std::string(&vec[0])`.

> another questions!!
>
> 1)is it because i casted char array name to char * ?

not sure where is that cast, but you had a UB as stated above.

> 2)how to use windows api without this char and char * mess .

MFC `CString` allows you to access internal buffer using GetBuffer(0) or GetBufferSetLength(100). std::string does not allow you to safely modify internal buffer, thats why its best to use std::vector. Actually `std::vector<TCHAR>` would be better, in case you use UNICODE builds where TCHAR will be wchar_t.

> 3)what is the difference between char array and char *?

both points to array of char type, so no much difference.

> the char array name is also constant pointer to the first element then what is the difference???

if it is `const char* nm = "alabama";` then it says you cannot modify nm array content

> 4)how to return char array from function in c ? in c++?

to safely return a char array, you should make sure its lifetime is longer that your function lifetime. This means either you have to allocate memory inside function,- or pass already allocated memory to your function.

> 5)what is the differnce between char * and const char * ? they both the same cuz the value being pointed is unchangeable!

`char*` is an array of type char that you can modify in your code, `const char*` is an array of char type you can only read.